# Android Custom CalendarView Event Color

Tags: android

I am using android CalendarView, I need to highlight some dates on the calendar, couldn't find any methods to do that, is there any tweak availalbe
if i can save some events on native calendar then would the calendarview will highlight those dates ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to highlight dates or events in the CalendarView, it's just for selecting dates.

However there are other libraries you can use such as:

- [android-calendar-view](https://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/)
- [Caldro](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid)